# (Windows) How to lock all applications (explorer, task manager etc.) and make only the browser active?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-7, windows-xp, system-administration

I'm trying to run only the browser in the system - locking access to everything else. Only the supervisor can resume the normal functioning of the system after giving a password.

This kind of activity is usually done by virus. Disabling the registry for Task manager etc. Does anyone know of any source available that does this? I might be able to pull it off in Windows XP. But have anyone tried this in Windows 7 ?

The aim is to to emulate the Chrome OS on Windows. Only the browser. Nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're after Kiosk Mode. Knowing that, a little searching gives a [guide](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-setup-windows-vista-and-7-as-a-kiosk/) to what to do.

Comment: Thank you very much! The term 'Kiosk' seems exactly what I was looking for. There are a lot of resources on Google documenting this.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, What you are attempting is **NOT** natively possible on windows.

You best bet would be to write a program that runs in the background and monitors for any processes apart from the browser being launched.

It should immediately terminate the "unauthorised" processes as soon as they are created.

Also using the group-policy manager restrict access to the task-manager to prevent the user from stopping this process.

Contact me if U require help in writing the above program

[2.6Kilohertz@gmail.com](http://mailto:2.6kilohertz@Gmail.com)

GOOD LUCK!!